# Multiple devices on a single Google account - App/Setting Syncing

Tags: sync, backup, google

I have a few Google Nexus devices that are all set up with the same Google Play account. They are all set to backup and restore and when setting up new devices they seem to pull down all the most recent changes I've made however if I download an app or make any changes they do not sync with each other.

Is there any way I can set this up to happen or any apps that can do this for me?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no built-in way to sync apps between devices. Google Play backups are generally only accessed when restoring apps onto a new device (or one that was factory reset).

If you have root on the devices, you can manually sync app data. You could copy the data folder for each app manually. Or you could use [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en) or any other backup app to do it for you.

With the paid version of Titanium Backup, you can back up and restore from Google Drive or Dropbox, so it can be done wirelessly. And you can set up schedules to automatically backup certain apps. Restoring on the other devices would still be a manual process, though.

Essentially, if the specific app developer didn't create a built-in way to sync itself across other devices, you'll have to do some tedious manual work to shuffle data around.